# Connect aspx to windows forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have an application in C# Windows Forms and I want to add a feature that is available only by jQuery. I implemented what I need in a new aspx file (new project). The question is, how do I connect it with my WinForms app? I need to send some data from my app to the website. These data are contained in a data structure of type Dictionary and I need them in the same format/structure in my website. Can I embed the website inside my form or do I have to call the aspx project from within my app?
Thanks.

Comment: I would love to know what you would like to do in jQuery that cannot be accomplished in a winforms app.

Comment: @anothershrubery I just need to represent my data with some nice effects. Actually if I could that inside my application that would be great. What I need jQuery for is to do this: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scrollable-timelines.html#1999-google-funded-by-major-venture-capital-firms . Do you know how to do it in Win Forms? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to post the data in some way to the website. Use a WebRequest with the data in the post to send the List data to the website as eg. XML.

Maybe it would be simpler to upload the results to a database and simply open the browser with some ID to point to the database results. (process.Run("iexplore http//website.aspx?id=124)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with the database?

Comment: Use some windows form code to upload the resulting list to the database

Pass through an ID value to the browser

Use some asp.net code to load the resulting list from the database

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you absolutely need it, see [Using ASP.NET Runtime in Desktop Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/usingaspruntime.aspx), But you are basically trying to attach bicycle pedals to a motor vehicle.

It can be accomplished with a panel with AutoScroll = true